# Roots with Same Size in a Family of Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, polynomials

Let $k\geq 3$ be an integer and define the polynomial $f_k(x):=x^{k}-2x^{k-1}-x-1$. By using elementary tools it is easy to prove that all roots of $f_k(x)$ are simple. However, I would need a little more, namely, that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $f_k(x)$ such that $|\alpha|=|\beta|$, then $\alpha$ is either $\beta$ or $\overline{\beta}$ (its complex conjugate).

I tried to use the standard approach by writing $\alpha=re^{i\theta}$ and $\beta=re^{i\gamma}$, with $r>0$ and $\theta,\gamma\in (-\pi,\pi]$. Now, it suffices to prove that $\theta=\pm \gamma$.

After many calculations I arrived in a trigonometric equality, however I had no idea how to deduce what I need from it and I was not able to think in another better approach for the original problem.

The trigonometric equality is the following:

$$
2r^{k-1}\cos(x/2)\cos(y/2)=r\cos((k-1)x/2)\cos((k-1)y/2)-2\cos((k-2)x/2)\cos((k-2)y/2),
$$
where $x:=\theta+\gamma$ and $y:=\theta-\gamma$.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what does it mean for a root to be simple?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent The multiplicity is 1

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take some positive radius $r$ and invert the roots of $f_k$ in the circle with radius $r$.  These inverted roots are exactly the roots of $$g_k(x) = x^k + r^2 x^{k-1} + 2 r^{2k-2} x - r^{2k}.$$ Any root $x_0$ of $p_k$ with norm $r$ is also a root of $g_k$.  However $(x+r^2) f_k(x) - (x - 2)g_k(x)$ is non-zero and has degree at most $2$.  Therefore, $f_k$ and $g_k$ have at most two common roots.  So there are at most two roots of $f_k$ with norm $r$.

Since $\pm x_0$ cannot both be roots of $f_k$ for any $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ (check!) this leaves the only option that roots with the same norm must be complex conjugates.

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution. Your approach holds for $f(x)$ whenever there exists polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, for which $h(x):=a(x)f(x)-b(x)x^mf(r^2/x)$ has degree at most $2$ (where $m=\deg f$). Is there any tool (other than case-by-case) to help to know when these polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ will exist? For example, I would like to find these polynomials, if any, for $f(x):=x^7-2x^6-x^5+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1$, and such that $\deg h\leq 3$. Any suggestion?

Comment: For $f, g$ of degree $7$ there are always $a, b$ of degree at most $3$ such that $a \cdot f + b \cdot g$ has degree at most $3$. The [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) (stop at degree $3$) or the kernel of a $7 \times 8$ matrix give (the coefficients of) such $a, b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the mentioned case, $g(x):=x^7f(r^2/x)$ divides $f(x)$, so I don't know how to use Euclidian Algorithm. In fact, I forgot to say that I need that $h(x)$ has degree at most $3$, but also that $h(x)$ is not the null polynomial.